# Calculate no of seconds between two UNIX timestamp

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, unix-timestamp

By using time.time() function, I am getting timestamps like this

```
start = 1606594554.4789438
end = 1606594553.8903968
```

I want to find no of seconds between these timestamps in this format, ex:- `6.532` seconds (upto 3 decimals)

I tried :-

```
 1. a = (float(f)-float(s))*(60*60*24) 
 2. datetime.timedelta(0, c) :-
```

But couldnt get output in desired format. `Output : 0:00:00.588547`

Is there any way to get the desired output ?

Comment: Probably not super useful, but at least it’s a good meme: https://m.youtube.com/watch?list=TLXr-H9YHrgq-gCqrNMQXVPEa3UOJwgusD&v=-5wpm-gesOY

Answer (score 1):

`time.time()` actually gives you floats.
you can use string formatting to get the precision you want:
`'%.1f seconds' %(end - start)`

Comment: `time()` did not always return a floating point number, hence the [Y2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

Comment: f-strings have also been around for a while now

Comment: My concern is what is the right way to calculate the difference between two Unix timestamps. Is my method correct?

Comment: If you want the difference in seconds, it's Ok to just subtract the start from the end